# How to handle stack traces from the Microsoft partner center?

Tags: c#, uwp, stack-trace, windows-store

I develop the UWP application. And published it via the Microsoft partner center. I get the crashes and hangs from the partner center with no understandable stack trace.

Also, I get the failure zip file where there are the following files (memory.csv, minidump.mdmp, WERInternalMetadata.xml).

How can I investigate these files for understanding the reason for failure?

Is there any way to understand the reason for crashes or hangs?

Here is an example of stacktrace:

```
Frame   Image   Function    Offset  
 "0"    "2FE3CB00.MYAPP-EXAMPLE"    "HANG_QUIESCE"  "0x0000000000000000"    
 "1"    "unknown.dll"   "[.ecxr]"   "0x0000000000000000"    
"2" "ntdll.dll" "ZwWaitForMultipleObjects"  "0x0000000000000000"    
"3" "KERNELBASE.dll"    "WaitForMultipleObjectsEx"  "0x0000000000000000"    
"4" "mrt100_app.dll"    "PalCompatibleWaitAny"  "0x0000000000000000"    
"5" "mrt100_app.dll"    "CLREventStatic::Wait"  "0x0000000000000000"    
"6" "mrt100_app.dll"    "WKS::gc_heap::background_gc_wait_lh"   "0x0000000000000000"    
"7" "mrt100_app.dll"    "WKS::gc_heap::a_fit_free_list_large_p" "0x0000000000000000"    
"8" "mrt100_app.dll"    "WKS::gc_heap::loh_try_fit" "0x0000000000000000"    
"9" "mrt100_app.dll"    "WKS::gc_heap::allocate_large"  "0x0000000000000000"    
"10"    "mrt100_app.dll"    "WKS::gc_heap::try_allocate_more_space" "0x0000000000000000"    
"11"    "mrt100_app.dll"    "WKS::gc_heap::allocate_large_object"   "0x0000000000000000"    
"12"    "mrt100_app.dll"    "WKS::GCHeap::Alloc"    "0x0000000000000000"    
"13"    "mrt100_app.dll"    "RhpGcAlloc"    "0x0000000000000000"    
"14"    "mrt100_app.dll"    "RhpNewArrayRare"   "0x0000000000000000"    
"15"    "SharedLibrary.dll" "System::RuntimeExceptionHelpers::ExceptionData.Serialize"  "0x0000000000000000"    
"16"    "SharedLibrary.dll" "System::Runtime`enter code here`ExceptionHelpers.SerializeExceptionsForDump"   "0x0000000000000000"    
"17"    "SharedLibrary.dll" "System::RuntimeExceptionHelpers.GenerateExceptionInformationForDump"   "0x0000000000000000"    
"18"    "System.Private.Interop.dll"    "System::Runtime::InteropServices::ExceptionHelpers.OriginateLanguageException" "0x0000000000000000"    
"19"    "System.Private.Interop.dll"    "System::Runtime::InteropServices::ExceptionHelpers.ReportUnhandledError"   "0x0000000000000000"    
"20"    "System.Private.Interop.dll"    "Internal::Interop::InteropCallbacks.ReportUnhandledError"  "0x0000000000000000"    
"21"    "MyApp.dll" "-" "0x0000000000000000"    
"22"    "unknown.dll"   "unknown"   "0x0000000000000000"    
"23"    "unknown.dll"   "unknown"   "0x0000000000000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already have the mdmp file, you could open it in the WinDbg app or Visual Studio. You could take a look at: [Dump files in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2022).

Besides, you could try to use [Visual Studio App Center](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/app-center/) in your app which get detailed crashed report as well and it could give the report in a readable way.